# Adding member variables of a class to a Map

Tags: java, hash, addition

I am having some trouble with this. I want to add the member variables to a map.

Here is my code:

Sprinter.java

```
public class Sprinter {
    private int age;
    private String name;
    private String address;

public Sprinter() {
}

public Sprinter(int age, String name, String address) {
    this.age = age;
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    return this.age = age;
}

public int getAge() {
    return this.age;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    return this.age = age;
}

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

 public void setAddress(String address) {
    return this.address = address;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return this.address;
}
```

Worker.java

```
Sprinter _s = new Sprinter(); 
_s.setAge(16);

_s.setName("Chris");

_s.setAddress("123 Street");
```

Map.java

```
public class Maper {
    private Sprinter _sp = new Sprinter();
    private static Map<String, Sprinter> map = new HashMap<String, Sprinter>();
public void printMap() {
    map.put(_sp.getName(), _sp);
    System.out.println(map);
```

I want the String in the map to be the key, and the values to be the age, address, and name fields from the Sprinter class. In my Worker.java class I use:

```
Maper _m = new Maper();
_m.printMap();
```

And my output is: {"Chris", "Chris"};
However, I want all of the variables to be added. Any advice?

Comment: Show the complete `Maper` class, or at least the `printMap`method

Comment: What do you mean by "my output"? I see that your `printMap` method only adds and entry to the map. It doesn't print anything.

Comment: Edited to add the print statement.

Comment: @Arrayoob Unless you're overriding the `toString()` method in the `Sprinter` class, the `printMap` method makes no sense for an output like `{"Chris", "Chris"}`. Please post the full source code of both the `Sprinter` and the `Maper` classes.

Answer (score 2):

A map relates a single key with a single value - it explicitly can't relate a single key ("Chris") with three different values (16, "Chris", "123 Street"). You have two obvious choices:

1. Use three different keys (e.g. `"Chris_age"` -> `16`, `"Chris_name"` -> `"Chris"`, `"Chris_address"` -> `"123 Street"`). This option is further complicated because the values are of different types (int vs String) so you'd need to declare your map as `Map<String, Object>` which is generally not great. The insert code would look something like:

   ```
   map.put(_sp.getName() + "_name", _sp.getName());
   map.put(_sp.getName() + "_age", _sp.getAge());
   map.put(_sp.getName() + "_address", _sp.getAddress());
   ```
2. The better option is to use a container object to hold the three values, and store that in the map. That's what the code you already have does. In that case, if you want the age you need to do something like:

   ```
   map.get("Chris").getAge();
   ```

Comment: Thanks, so something like map.get(_sp.getName().getAge());

Comment: @Arrayoob I think you mean `map.get(_sp.getName()).getAge();`.

Comment: That would certainly work, but I question why you'd do it - you already have `_sp` which is the Sprinter object, so in that case you can just call `_sp.getAge()` directly and not hit the map at all. Think of the map as a place to keep your sprinters - when you need one you pull it out and get whichever property you need. If you already have the sprinter you need - you're all set! The map comes into play when you know the name of the sprinter you want but you don't actually have a reference to it.

Comment: Does the put and get method work different with Maps like this?

Comment: @adamreeve Well, suppose I were to make name a variable, like:    String name = "Burt"; and then _s.setName(name);

Comment: Just to add, I want to add all of these values to a Map first.